# cypress.io: contains() not waiting for element

Tags: coded-ui-tests, cypress

We are writing UI tests with cypress, which is usually quite simple to use. But again and again I stumble over a tedious waiting problem.

The scenario is pretty simple. The user clicks on the search button. Then he selects one of the elements with a certain text. Here's the code:

```
cy.get('#search-button').click();
cy.contains('Test item 1').click();
cy.get('#cheapest-offer-button').click();
```

The third click event fails, because already `cy.contains('Test item 1')` doesn't wait for the page and the element to be rendered. From what I can see in the test steps, it simply clicks in the middle of the page, which does essentially nothing. So all subsequent steps fail of course.

However if I add a `wait()` between the calls like this:

```
cy.get('#search-button').click();
cy.wait(2000);
cy.contains('Test item 1').click();
cy.get('#cheapest-offer-button').click();
```

The page is rendered correctly, `Test item 1` appears, is clicked and all subsequent steps succeed.

According the [best practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Unnecessary-Waiting) the `wait()` call should not be necessary and therefore should be avoided. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's a bit hard to envision what is going on, can you show the DOM? (or describe the elements and what you know to be happening behind the clicks). Often you can replace a `cy.wait()` with a `cy.contains(selector, newContent)` where **newContent** is a piece of text that indicates a fetch has completed.

Comment: `cy.contains('Test item 1')` is finding something, despite it not yet being visible.  cypress will throw an exception and fail the test if it can't find the element.  Take a look in the command output on the left to see what that call is returning.  You may need to change how you're locating that element to make it more specific, or maybe adding a `.should("be.visible")` will get it working.  Posting a screen capture of the command log and your HTML will help us figure it out easier.

Comment: I believe it also could be used like `cy.get(selector).contains('Expected text')`

Answer (score 9):

### tl;dr

Give a bigger timeout for `contains`:

```js
cy.get('#search-button').click();
cy.contains('Test item 1', { timeout: 4000 }).click();
cy.get('#cheapest-offer-button').click();
```

### Explanation

As many Cypress commands, [`contains` have a second argument](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Arguments) which accepts an option object. You can pass the amount of milliseconds the command should wait in the `timeout` key like this:

```js
.contains('Stuff', { timeout: 5000 }) // Timeout after 5 secs
```

This way the command will behave like if you added a `wait` before it, but if the command was successful it won't wait out all the time like `wait` does.

The [official Cypress docs on timeouts](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Applying-Timeouts) explains this technique: how it works, how it should be done and how it affects chained assertions.

If the reason why you can't click the item is visibility then you can try `.click({ force: true })`, although this should be a last resort since it might hide actual bugs.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is common issue https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/695.

Solution is to force cypress to wait for all async operations like in frameworks based on Selenium webdriver. It is much more quickly than cy.wait() 
Do implement method:

```
function waitForBrowser() { 
   cy.window().then(win => {
      return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => win['requestIdleCallback'](resolve));
   });
}
```

And just use it like this:

```
cy.get('#search-button').click();
waitForBrowser();
cy.contains('Test item 1').click();
cy.get('#cheapest-offer-button').click();
```

If you use **Angular**, better to use **waitForAngular** instead of **waitForBrowser**

```
function waitForAngular() {
  return cy.window().then(win => {
      return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let testabilities = win['getAllAngularTestabilities']();
        if (!testabilities) {
            return reject(new Error('No testabilities. Check Angular API'));
        }
        let count = testabilities.length;
        testabilities.forEach(testability => testability.whenStable(() => {
            count--;
            if (count !== 0) return;
            resolve();
        }));
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: I did try using this approach, but I got no good result. Sorry !!

Comment: Works :) too bad we have to manually do this... For me it worked well in Cypress 3.8.2 now in 4.4.0 I had to wait for Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to those posted above is to use something like

```
cy.contains('Test item 1').should('exist').click()
```

or
cy.contains('Test item 1').should('be.visible').click()

I am not sure why this works but it does, it doesn't require setting a specific timeout.

Alternatively no one else has suggested using

```
cy.server()
cy.route()
```

and

```
cy.wait('@routeAlias')
```

But that requires more information than in the OP

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to reach a span with certain value.
I fixed it by providing more specific path to the span instead of getting all span elements in the page.

```
cy.get('span').contains('Round ID') //not working
cy.get('.details span').contains('Round ID') //worked
```

So you can try to be more specific when getting elements of the type which you want to target.
Another option is to wait()...

Answer (score 0):

You might be already aware that Cypress commands are Asynchronous. So if some command depends with another action then its better to write it in subroutine of its dependent action.

```
cy.get('#search-button').click().then(() => {
    cy.contains('Test item 1').should('be.visible').click();
    cy.get('#cheapest-offer-button').should('be.visible').click();
});
```